# Node/Express: Database being printed on screen rather than index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, cpanel

So, I'm using Node, but all that's printed on the screen is my database in JSON format and not index.html. This doesn't occur when I use localhost, so I have no idea why it does show my index page. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening'));

app.get('/api', (request, response) => {
    db.find({}, (err, data) => {
        response.json(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand your question properly but based on the code you will get a JSON response on  `localhost:3000/api` and a blank screen on `localhost:300` as you have not rendered or called for any views in your code.

You can use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` to access your directory and then use `res.sendFile('index.html')` to render index HTML file on any route you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Where should I put these in my app.js?

Comment: Hey! You already have the express.static line, sorry missed it while writing the answer.
just write `res.sendFile('index.html')` inside any of the routes, in this case, inside your `/api` route. 
Also actually your question says DB printed on screen rather than `index.html` , meaning you want this DB to be on the index file.
For that you need to specifically call the DB using API's onto your HTML file and display in there.